# Is every Android phone GPS Enabled or not?

Tags: android, gps

I am developing a location based application but I am confused whether every Android phone has GPS enabled or not?

And if GPS is not available and if we use GPS settings API, then what is the result?
is any error or not..?

please help me..

Comment: You can test by creating an emulator that does not have GPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some android devices don't have a GPS.

For more informations on how to get the location of a user, you should read the [**Obtaining User Location**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) section of the documentation : it contains quite  of bit of notes and code samples.